# Rails: Checking Formtastic CSS (on Bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, formtastic

**Problem:** Where can I find/edit the original css file for formtastic?

**Reason:** I cant change the "width" of text forms as they seem to be set to some value automatically. I want to check the original css file if it forces the width of all text forms.

**Environment:**

```
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass'
 gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'
```

If anyone knows the direct answer to why I cant change the width of text forms (size, cols attributes do not work) I'd appreciate that answer more. Thank you for your help!

**Image:**

[image]

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <% @post = Post.new %>
 <%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name, :hint => "enter your name", :input_html => { :rows => 10, :width => 10 } %>
    <%= f.input :content, :hint => "enter the content", :input_html => { :rows => 10, :width => 100000 } %>

<% end %>
<%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %><% end %></div>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="formtastic post" id="new_post" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="wFcjDR0nzm2B3yl2XtUxzlQz0CWplYf2nKiq+xgDpXo=" /></div>

<fieldset class="inputs">
<div class="string input required stringish control-group" id="post_name_input"><label class=" control-label" for="post_name">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><div class="controls"><input id="post_name" maxlength="255" name="post[name]" rows="10" type="text" width="10" /><span class="help-block">enter your name</span></div></div>

<div class="text input required control-group" id="post_content_input"><label class=" control-label" for="post_content">Content<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><div class="controls"><textarea id="post_content" name="post[content]" rows="10" width="100000"></textarea><span class="help-block">enter the content</span></div></div></fieldset>
```

**Summary:** Why is this happening, and where can I find the formtastc.css file? It's not in the assets folder but the page is somehow loading the css.

Answer (score 1):

Formtastic.css file is located in the developer's assets (it's in the gem so you cant check it  in the Windows explorer.

[Formtastic.css](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/formtastic.css)

Here, The code below was causing the trouble

```
/* TEXTAREA OVERRIDES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.formtastic .text textarea {
  width:72%;
}

.formtastic .text textarea[cols] {
  width:auto;
  max-width:72%;
}
```

I just solved the problem by using class **span** instead of trying to fix the width. But you can add your own css to change the width and that'd bring the same result in my opinion.

```
<%= f.input :content, :label => 'content', :input_html => {  :rows => 5, :class => 'span10' } %>
```